# Is it possible to listen for superclass property changes in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'd like to create an "reload" setter for a property, that I'd like to keep in a trait. Then any subclasses that implement the trait would use their own getter, but the trait's setter. I don't want to add any extra annotations to existing properties. Here's a clarification:

```
trait Tr {
    abstract String getS()
    void setS(String value) {
        ((GroovyObject) this).setProperty('s', value)
        reloadOnSChange()
    }

    void reloadOnSChange() {
        // do something when S is changed
    }
}

class Cl implements Tr {
    String s
}

Cl cl = new Cl()
cl.s = 'hello world' // reloadOnSChange should be called
```

Is such a property listener possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use trait for that then you have to do it differently than implementing `void getS(String value)` method, because Groovy compiler generates `Cl.getS(String value)` method that shadows the method implemented in the `Tr` trait.

Alternatively your trait can provide implementation of `void setProperty(String name, Object value)` method that if called for property `s`, it executes `reloadOnSChange()` method. Consider following example:

```groovy
trait Tr {
    abstract String getS()
    abstract void setS(String s)

    void reloadOnSChange() {
        // do something when S is changed
        println "RELOAD"
    }

    void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
        metaClass.setProperty(this, name, value)
        if (name == 's') {
            reloadOnSChange()
        }
    }
}

class Cl implements Tr {
    String s
}

Cl cl = new Cl()
cl.s = 'hello world'

println "Dump: ${cl.dump()}"
```

Output:

```
RELOAD
Dump: <Cl@6580cfdd s=hello world>
```

The main downside is that this `setProperty` method will be executed for every property, so it may generate some overhead. At some point JIT should optimize the code and make sure that this `if` statement is executed only when property name is  equal to `s`.